# Is it possible to sort an array of object by property of another object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

So i have an array of object that looks like this:

```
    group: [
0: {id: "16", name: "P1", courseId: "6", mentorId: "1", chatUrl: false, students: {0: 1, 1: 10, 2: 11},…}
1: {id: "17", name: "C1", courseId: "7", mentorId: "3", chatUrl: false, students: {0: 15, 1: 16, 2: 18},…}
2: {id: "22", name: "P2", courseId: "6", mentorId: "1", chatUrl: false, students: {0: 12, 1: 13, 2: 9},…}
3: {id: "23", name: "C2", courseId: "7", mentorId: "3", chatUrl: false, students: {0: 17, 1: 19, 2: 20},…}
4: {id: "24", name: "DEV", courseId: "10", mentorId: "1", chatUrl: false,…}].
```

i'm trying to sort it by mentor name which is property of object in another array that looks like this:

```
mentor: [
0: {id: "0", firstName: "Daniel",  about: false,…}
1: {id: "1", firstName: "Mark",  aboutl:false,…}
2: {id: "3", firstName: "Eric", about: false,…}
3: {id: "6", firstName: "John", about: false,…} ]
```

The groups are related to mentors by property mentorId, so i have to compare property mentorId from group array with id from mentor array to get all mentors for groups and then sort the group by those mentors firstName. Is this even possible?

The output should display all the groups sorted alphabeticly by mentor firstname, something like this:

```
group: [
0: {id: "23", name: "C2", courseId: "7", mentorId: "3", chatUrl: false, students: {0: 17, 1: 19, 2: 20},…}
    1: {id: "17", name: "C1", courseId: "7", mentorId: "3", chatUrl: false, students: {0: 15, 1: 16, 2: 18},…}
    2: {id: "22", name: "P2", courseId: "6", mentorId: "1", chatUrl: false, students: {0: 12, 1: 13, 2: 9},…}
    3: {id: "16", name: "P1", courseId: "6", mentorId: "1", chatUrl: false, students: {0: 1, 1: 10, 2: 11},…}
    4: {id: "24", name: "DEV", courseId: "10", mentorId: "1", chatUrl: false,…}
]
```

Comment: how the output will look like?

Comment: What do you mean with "sort by mentor name"? Sort it in an ascending order? Or sort it in the order the mentor names appear in the mentor array?

Comment: I edited the question, it should sort the groups alphabetically by mentors firstName, asscending or descending, its not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first sort the mentors array by firstName property and then create an object where the key is the id and the value is index of that object in the sorted array. Then you can just use `sort` method on groups array and sort by the value of `mentorId` property in order object.

```js
const groups = [{"id":"16","name":"P1","courseId":"6","mentorId":"1","chatUrl":false,"students":{"0":1,"1":10,"2":11}},{"id":"17","name":"C1","courseId":"7","mentorId":"3","chatUrl":false,"students":{"0":15,"1":16,"2":18}},{"id":"22","name":"P2","courseId":"6","mentorId":"1","chatUrl":false,"students":{"0":12,"1":13,"2":9}},{"id":"23","name":"C2","courseId":"7","mentorId":"3","chatUrl":false,"students":{"0":17,"1":19,"2":20}},{"id":"24","name":"DEV","courseId":"10","mentorId":"1","chatUrl":false}]
const mentors = [{"id":"0","firstName":"Daniel","about":false},{"id":"1","firstName":"Mark","aboutl":false},{"id":"3","firstName":"Eric","about":false},{"id":"6","firstName":"John","about":false}]

mentors.sort((a, b) => a.firstName.localeCompare(b.firstName))
const order = mentors.reduce((r, { id }, i) => (r[id] = i, r), {})
groups.sort((a, b) => order[a.mentorId] - order[b.mentorId])
console.log(groups)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var group= [
     
     {id: "17", name: "C1", courseId: "7", mentorId: "3", chatUrl: false, students: {0: 15, 1: 16, 2: 18}},
     {id: "16", name: "P1", courseId: "6", mentorId: "1", chatUrl: false, students: {0: 1, 1: 10, 2: 11}},
     {id: "22", name: "P2", courseId: "6", mentorId: "1", chatUrl: false, students: {0: 12, 1: 13, 2: 9}},
     {id: "23", name: "C2", courseId: "7", mentorId: "3", chatUrl: false, students: {0: 17, 1: 19, 2: 20}},
     {id: "24", name: "DEV", courseId: "10", mentorId: "1", chatUrl: false}] 

var mentor=[
    {id: "0", firstName: "Daniel",  about: false},
    {id: "1", firstName: "Mark",  aboutl:false},
    {id: "3", firstName: "Eric", about: false},
    {id: "6", firstName: "John", about: false} 
]

group = group.sort( (a,b) => {
    for(i=0;i<mentor.length;i++){
        if (a.mentorId===mentor[i].id){a.mentorName=mentor[i].firstName}
        if (b.mentorId===mentor[i].id){b.mentorName=mentor[i].firstName}
        
    }
    if(a.mentorName<b.mentorName){return -1} 
    else if(a.mentorName==b.mentorName){return 0} 
    else{return 1}
});
console.log(group);
```